# Concurrent Connection Test

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, concurrency, dd-wrt

So I ran into a network problem the other day and I was trying to find a way to test for this problem in the future.

I had a lot of users online at once and hit my routers max IP connection limit (not DHCP! TCP/UDP connections.)

Once I figured out what the problem was it was fairly simple to fix however I was wondering if there is any way to simulate this kind of activity? Everything worked fine when I tested it, it wasn't until I had 150+ users that I discoved I had a problem.

I have spent the last 3-4hrs looking for such a test/audit tool. Here is what I found:

1. http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/ -DDoS simulator (can't make it work, barly get +300 connections)
2. http://stevesouders.com/hpws/max-connections.php -Browser concurrent connection tester (This hits the browser limit (6 in chrome) w/o making a dent on my router even open in 70+ tabs at the same time)
3. http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/31103-how-we-test-hardware-routers-revision-3 -Some tool linked about halfway down the page (Reads like its exactly what I want, however it barely has a noticable effect on my router.)
4. http://www.http-kit.org/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html -Concurrent HTTP connection simulator (This one seems like it would do what I want, but my linux-foo is limited and I can't get it working. *tear*)

So do you guys have a tool to test your routers with? I would love something that does both TCP/UDP.

(btw, for anyone misunderstanding I'm not trying to test "speed", just sheer number of connections)

Thanks!
Kz